# Rails callback initiator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have ActiveRecord schema that is matched to an external API schema.

What I'm trying to achieve is to conditionally decide if to call external destroy API

I have this structure:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :spoiler, dependent: :destroy
    before_destroy: :destroy_external

    def destroy_external
        # API call to destroy Car. AUTOMATICALLY DESTROYS EXTERNAL SPOILER connected to Car
    end
end

class Spoiler < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :car
    before_destroy: :destroy_external

    def destroy_external
        # Call API destroy spoiler ONLY IF the callback was initiated directly and not via car destroy dependency
    end
end
```

If I want to destroy only the Spoiler (both locally and external) I do:

```
spoiler.destroy!
```

And it makes a call to API to destroy the external spoiler and then destroys it locally.

But if I want to destroy a Car (both locally and external) I do:

```
car.destroy!
```

I don't want the destroy_external method on the Spoiler to be executed, or detect that it was called via Car callback and skip the API call, since the API automatically destroys the spoiler that is connected to the Car, so no destroy spoiler API is necessary.

The 'hack' is to remove the destroy dependency and add `spoiler.delete!` inside the `car.destroy_external` method, but this is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need    `has_one :spoiler, dependent: :delete` in the `Car` model.

It will delete data from database but will not trigger any callbacks.

[Explanation](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all-in-rails-models/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I knew about the delete callbacks, that delete directly from the DB without calling the destroy callback, but I had a mistake in the original code.

When using destroy dependency, use :destroy both on has_one and on has_many associations.

But for delete, we use :delete on has_one and :delete_all for has_many associations.